# C# Converting Hex Values

Tags: c#, hex

I am reading a list of assigned rights from an exchange mailbox, these values are returned via the AccessFlag property which returns 20001 in Hex, it looks like 2000 represents the READ permission and the 1 represents FULL permission.

What I want to do is display that value as READ & FULL permissions set.

Comment: I'm assuming the 20001 above should be 2001?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want is as a string, you need an enum.

So if you have something like this:

```
[Flags]
enum Permissions
{
  Read = 0x20000,
  Full = 0x00001
}
```

Then you can cast your return value and use ToString()

```
string val = ((Permissions )myValue).ToString();
```

And it will come out something like this:

```
Read, Full
```

Note that the Flags attribute is important for this type of enum.

Comment: You missed the () on your ToString() call in your code snippet.

Comment: +1: Lovely trick :) It shows "Read, Full" for me (I had to try it out)

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I'm not sure what you're asking for.

If you have a value from the AccessFlag, and you want to see if it has either of those flag, you can use a bitwise and e.g.

```
If((accessFlag & 0x2000) != 0) // It has FULL
If((accessFlag & 0x1) != 0) // It has READ
If((accessFlag & 0x2001) != 0) // It has READ AND FULL
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bitwise XOR operator to filter out the values you need and deduce the permission set from them.